# Какие версии C++ поддерживает MS Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне нужно чтобы код компилировался для MS Visual C++ именно версии 6.0 Какие версии стандарта языка он поддерживает, и как их можно переключить.

Comment: 11 стандарт и выше он 100% не поддерживает. 98 - должен. Но вот он это делает с своими особенностями. К примеру, объявленная в for переменная цикла будет видна за его пределами (сейчас это не так).

Comment: Никакие, так как Visual C++ 6.0 вышел еще до появления первого стандарта (точнее примерно одновременно с ним). Тогда был "просто С++" (C + классы + шаблоны). ¿А зачем вам в 2021 году понадобился Visual C++ 6.0?

Comment: @user7860670 Да уж, бедненько, там наверно ничего нормального ещё нету. Для олимпиады.

Comment: Да там уже почти все есть, по сравнению с++11 не хватает только вывода типов, перегрузок для rvlaue и агрессивного constexpr. Ну и классов из буста в стандартную библиотеку еще не натаскали. ¿А вы уверены, что нужен именно 6.0, а не на 16? ¿Или с Visual Studio 6.0 не путаете? Это же дичь какая-то.